# C++ code to find BSSID OF associated network

Tags: c++, wireless, ubuntu-10.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want to know the ESSID of wireless network via C++ in UBUNTU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937757/want-to-know-the-essid-of-wireless-network-via-c-in-ubuntu)

Hello

I have written the following code which is a part of a project. It is used to find the ESSID of the current associated network. However it has a flaw that it also the displays the ESSID of the network with which I am not associated i.e. if I try to associate myself with a wireless n/w and if it is unsuccessfull i.e. NO DHCP OFFERS ARE RECEIVED, then also it will display the that ESSID with which I have made  my attempt.

If possible try to give me a ioctl call to find the BSSID of current associated wireless n/w as it is the only way with which I can mark b/w associated and non associated.

CODE:

```
int main (void)
{
    int errno;
    struct iwreq wreq;

    CStdString result = "None";

    int sockfd;
    char * id;
    char ESSID[100];
    memset(&wreq, 0, sizeof(struct iwreq));

    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open socket \n");
        fprintf(stderr, "errno = %d \n", errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
        return result ;
    }
    CLog::Log(LOGINFO,"Socket opened successfully");

    FILE* fp = fopen("/proc/net/dev", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        // TBD: Error
        return result;
    }

    char* line = NULL;
    size_t linel = 0;
    int n;
    char* p;
    int linenum = 0;
    while (getdelim(&line, &linel, '\n', fp) > 0)
    {
        // skip first two lines
        if (linenum++ < 2)
            continue;

        p = line;
        while (isspace(*p))
        ++p;

        n = strcspn(p, ": \t");
        p[n] = 0;

        strcpy(wreq.ifr_name, p);

        id = new char[IW_ESSID_MAX_SIZE+100];
        wreq.u.essid.pointer = id;
        wreq.u.essid.length = 100;
        if ( ioctl(sockfd,SIOCGIWESSID, &wreq) == -1 ) {
            continue;
        }
        else 
        {
            strcpy(ESSID,id);
            return ESSID;
        }
        free(id);
    }

    free(line);
    fclose(fp);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: According to http://www.cryer.co.uk/glossary/s/ssid.htm , the difference between ESSID and BSSID is that ESSID applies to wireless networks with an access point and BSSID applies to ad-hoc wireless network.  I imagine looking up the SSID via C++ would use the same code either way, though maybe some of the api calls would use different flags.  Regardless, your deleted answer dooes make it clear that you are aware of the post you are duplicating, but I think you'd need an explicit reference to it in your answer to avoid being closed.  And maybe a bounty would help, too.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention whether you were using an independent basic service set or not (i.e., an ad-hoc network with no controlling access point), so if you're not trying to create an ad-hoc network, then the BSSID should be the MAC address of the local access point.  The `ioctl()` constant you can use to access that information is `SIOCGIWAP`.  The `ioctl` payload information will be stored inside of your `iwreq` structure at `u.ap_addr.sa_data`.

Comment: But here's is the take if I use SIOCGIWAP it displays the BSSID of the network with which I lasted ATTEMPTED to make connection.I have gone throe the iwconfig library in that it uses some iw_ether_cmp to check bou I can't Understand it fully.Wish someone could help me.