# Can I get SSID and MAC address from C code in Linux?

Tags: c, networking, ssid

I am writing a C backup program for my **Majaro Linux**. It must backup files at a certain time in my home local server only if I am connecting to my home network. So I need to get an **SSID** and a **MAC address** a current network to decide if it is my network or not.

Is there **Linux**(Arch) default commands, C library functions or files, contain this information?

I already tried some **Linux** tools, *ifconfig* for example, but it is useless for me.

Help!

Comment: maybe libpcap library helps to get some information about your network in c program.

Comment: you might want to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19733653/2331445

Comment: This is really a linux question, not a C question. What you want are linux libraries that vend that data. Link to those libraries in your C code, and you're good. Here's one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779715/how-to-get-mac-address-of-your-machine-using-a-c-program

Comment: [This](https://github.com/bmegli/wifi-scan) is a good implementation of a wifi-scanner that might be of interested for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Done

Thank you all for your help, especially to [Iliya Iliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245017/iliya-iliev) and to this [library](https://github.com/bmegli/wifi-scan).
It works perfectly.

It exactly what I've been searching for!

I just add it to my main project.

```
#include "../wifi_scan.h"
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <unistd.h> 

const char *bssid_to_string(const uint8_t bssid[BSSID_LENGTH], char  bssid_string[BSSID_STRING_LENGTH])
    {
        snprintf(bssid_string, BSSID_STRING_LENGTH, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
             bssid[0], bssid[1], bssid[2], bssid[3], bssid[4], bssid[5]);
        printf("%x\n", bssid[5]);
        return bssid_string;
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv){

        struct wifi_scan *wifi=NULL;
        struct station_info station;
        char mac[BSSID_STRING_LENGTH]; 

        wifi=wifi_scan_init(argv[1]);
        wifi_scan_station(wifi, &station);

        printf("ssid = %s mac = %s \n", station.ssid, bssid_to_string(station.bssid, mac));

        wifi_scan_close(wifi);

    }
```